# An infinite cyclic group has a unique subgroup of index $m$ for any integer $m \geq 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite cyclic group. Show that for any integer $m \geq 1$, there exists a unique subgroup of index $m$. My attempt is consider $G=(\mathbb{Z},+)$. Consider a subgroup $m\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then the index $[\mathbb{Z}:m\mathbb{Z}]=m$. This shows the existence part. Bt I'm stuck at uniqueness part. Anyone can help ?

Comment: Do you know how to classify all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$?  (If not, for $H < \mathbb{Z}$ ($H \neq 0$), consider the smallest $m \in H \cap \mathbb{N}$ and compare $H$ to $m \mathbb{Z}$.)  Once you have the complete list, you can prove uniqueness by checking that no other subgroup besides $m \mathbb{Z}$ has index $m$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you've got *existence*, and you're only a step away from *uniqueness*.

**TIP:**
 Recall that all *cyclic groups of infinite order* are *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{Z}.$ It follows that all subgroups $H\leq \mathbb{Z}$ with finite index $m \ge 1$ are of the form $m\mathbb{Z}$. You can classify all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ by noting that for $H \leq \mathbb{Z}, H\neq 0$, and considering the smallest $m\in H\cap \mathbb{N}$ and compare $H$ to $m\mathbb{Z}$.

*So you can prove uniqueness* by showing that no other subgroup besides $m\mathbb{Z}$ has index $m$.

E.g., to make explicit the uniqueness of $H = m\mathbb{Z}$, assume, then, that there exists another subgroup $H' \leq G$ with index $m \geq 1$ such that $[G \cong \mathbb{Z}:H']= m$. Then we have that $H' = m\mathbb{Z} = H$.

Hence...

Comment: This is what I was trying to note the OP.+

Comment: I do not quite understand your last statement ' Then we have that $H^{\prime}=m\mathbb{Z}=H$'. Why the first equality holds ?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Show that all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $m\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Nice Amr +1$$$$$

Comment: @YACP and ofcourse I did not want $\{z\in\mathbb{Z}|\frac{z}{0}\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. I will edit my answer. Thank you

Comment: Okay. I deleted my comments here since them became obsolete.