# Prove that a group of infinite order must have a proper subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that the group of infinite order is also cylic. How would one prove that? I am quite stuck.

Comment: If it is cyclic and generated by $x$, consider $x^2$.

Comment: Note that any cyclic group of infinite order is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, which is known to have proper subgroups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An infinite cyclic group has a unique subgroup of index $m$ for any integer $m \geq 1$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292131/an-infinite-cyclic-group-has-a-unique-subgroup-of-index-m-for-any-integer-m)

Comment: The title and the question are quite different. Which one do you mean? Besides, the group generated by 1 is always a subgroup of any group, so...

Answer (score 8):

Take any $x\in G$.

If $|x|<\infty$, then $x$ generates a finite subgroup $\langle x\rangle$. Since $G$ is infinite, the subgroup generated by $x$ is proper.

If $|x|=\infty$, then $\langle x\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Take any proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ and use the isomorphism. For $n\geq 2$, $\langle x^n\rangle$ will be a proper subgroup of $\langle x\rangle$, and of $G$.